# 2 subtotal lines showing on excel pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, subtotal

I have an Excel pivot table which summarises values using the MAX function. I've set the row subtotal to SUM the max values and display it at the top of each group.

For some reason I still get a subtotal which shows the max for each group as well and I cant turn it off.

Table shows something like

Category    Customer    1 Month     3 Months    6 Months
Customers           1       1       1
Customers           1018        4726        10511
Customers over £10,000      1       1       1
Customers over £10,000      26      237     542

Comment: Sorry that didn't display as written.

Comment: suffice to say that there are 2 categories "customer" and "customer over 10000". For each over the columns (1 month, 2 month etc.) it displays 2 total lines. one with the correct sum values and one which shows the max value which is the one I want to get rid of please